# Create Table with CTAS and Partition

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

i have created a table per CTAS and PARTITION, looks all good but not partition has any rows.
can someone tell what i am doing wrong?

table tickets:

```
region number(1),
ticket_number varchar2(10)
```

and then the CTAS with partition and index

```
CREATE TABLE tickets2 
PARTITION BY list (region)
 (
    PARTITION R1 VALUES (1),
    PARTITION R2 VALUES (2),
    PARTITION R3 VALUES (3),
    PARTITION RX VALUES (DEFAULT)
   ) AS
SELECT * FROM tickets
;
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON tickets2 (region, ticket_number) NOLOGGING
```

all runs without any problems or errors but if i checked the partitions in TOAD under Table Partitions there are no rows for the partitions.

Comment: please add the insert statements you have used to insert values in tickets2 table.

Comment: Does PAation mean PARTITION?

Comment: I suspect that Toad is using the ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS view to get the count of rows in the partition, and I believe this is only be updated when statistics are gathered on the table. Gather statistics on the table then check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try running this command and see ?

```
select * from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'tickets'; 

select count(*) from tickets partition (r1);
select count(*) from tickets partition (r2);
select count(*) from tickets partition (r3);
select count(*) from tickets partition (rx);
```

This command should display the rows in each partitions created for the table.

Comment: counting works, getting the real number of rows for each partition... after that i can see the number of rows in schema browser. it means it worked or must every partiotion initiate at first? i am new to the topic partitioning

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by ... "must every partition initiate at first?". Once you insert new rows, they will show up in the corresponding partition.

Comment: yeah but i cant see the number of rows in the schema browser table definition, i must run your query first. but now over knight i see all rows of every partition and see in the column "last analyzed" a time at night between 23 and 24 o'clock, that is what i mean. can i analyze the partition in the CTAS operation?